# An unproved statement from Gohberg and Krein

Tags: functional-analysis

In the book: Introduction to the Theory of Linear Nonselfadjoint Operators in Hilbert Space, by Gohberg and Krein, page 3, there is an unproved statement that seems to be pulled from nowhere.

Let P be a projection, Q=I-P, range of P invariant under A so QAP=0.

They show:

A=(P+Q)A(P+Q)=PAP + PAQ + QAQ (This is fine).

Then

A=(QAQ+P)(I+PAQ)(Q+PAP) (Also understand)

Assuming invertibility of the first and last factor, noting the middle is invertible as (I-PAQ), the next statement is

A^(-1) = (Q+PAP)^(-1)(I-PAQ)(P+QAQ)^(-1)

and therefore

PA^(-1)P=P(Q+PAP)^(-1)P

QA^(-1)Q=Q(P+QAQ)^(-1)Q

Now for the question. The next step is to "observe"

P(Q+PAP)^(-1)P = (Q+PAP)^(-1) - Q.

to arrive at

(Q+PAP)^(-1) = PA^(-1)P + Q.

I don't see the "observation" to be true. How can it be shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Q$, $P$ and $Q + PAP$ (and therefore also $(Q + PAP)^{-1}$ commute.
So $P (Q + PAP)^{-1} P - (Q + PAP)^{-1}  = (Q + PAP)^{-1} P - (Q + PAP)^{-1} = - (Q + PAP)^{-1} Q$.  Now $Q = (Q + PAP) Q$ so $-(Q + PAP)^{-1} Q = -Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much! The commuting of the indicated inverse with P is the key, which I failed to think about. Mental block. I am grateful for the assist.